# Form inputs and conditional javascript submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function to sum values a form and compare with a another value.

**[Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/La18Lcns/10)**.

**HTML :**

```
<input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">
<input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">
<input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">
<input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">

<button type='button' id="button-cart">Add To Cart</button>
<div class="errorQuantity"></div>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function()
{
    var MaxSelectionNum = "7";
    var sum = 0;

    // Loop through all inputs with names that start
    // with "option-quantity" and sum their values
    $('input[name^="option-quantity"]').each(function()
    {
        var val = $(this).val() || 0;
        if(val != 0) {
          val = val.replace('.', '');
          val = val.replace(',', '.');
          val = parseFloat(val);
        }

        console.log(val);
        sum += val;
    });

    if (sum < MaxSelectionNum)
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").html("Please select 7 meals").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").html("You have select greater than 7: meal count:  " + sum).show();
    }
});
```

This work, but i want to validate form before submit.

If the sum < 7, do not submit.

How can i do it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your inputs inside a form and call submit in your script after validation.

**HTML :**

```
<form ip='my-form'>  
    <input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">
    <input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">
    <input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">
    <input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">

    <button type='button' id="button-cart">Add To Cart</button>
    <div class="errorQuantity"></div>  
</form>
```

**JS :**

```
if (sum < MaxSelectionNum)
{
    $(".errorQuantity").html("Please select 7 meals").show();
}
else
{
    $('#my-form').submit();
}
```

**NOTE :** You should change the names of inputs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the validation function on [`.submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event of the form.

```
<form id='my-form' action="your action goes here">  
    <input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">
    <input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">
    <input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">
    <input class="fieldToValidate" name="option-quantity">

    <input type="submit" value="Add to Card" />
    <div class="errorQuantity"></div>  
</form>

    $(function(){
    $("#my-form").submit(function(){
        var maxSelectionNum = "7";
        var sum = 0;
        $("input:text[name='option-quantity']").each(function(index, val) {
            sum += parseInt(this.value, 10);
        });

        if (sum >= maxSelectionNum) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $(".errorQuantity").html("Please select 7 meals").show();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/La18Lcns/15/)

Comment: Can you check why form continue if the sum is not the total value ?

http://jsfiddle.net/La18Lcns/17/